# The meaning of été in "On a toujours été..."

Tags: vocabulaire, usage

I'm having a hard time trying to understand what the meaning of this phrase is:

> "On a toujours été...".

The dictionary tells me that "été" means summer but I can't see how that definition translate into anything meaningful.

Comment: Welcome to French Language SE! It's hard to know what level to answer at, because I don't know where you are in your French. One answer would be: *été* is the participe passé of *être*. This is the form used in the passé composé, which is the usual past tense in French. Since *être* means "to be", *été* means "been". The translation of the sentence is "We have always been..." If any part of that explanation is unclear, please add a comment or edit your question, and it might be possible to write a detailed answer that would help you more.

Comment: Hi, I'm a beginner and I didn't know I was dealing with the verb "être". Your comment has answered my question. Thanks Luke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following @Luke Sawczak's nice comment the sentence

> On a toujours été...

is the past form (one of them) of the sentence

> On est toujours...(present tense)

In particular, this is the so-called passé composé (perfect tense in French learning books for Anglophones) which is composed as follows:

> auxiliary verb (avoir or être)+past participle (participe passé) of
>   the conjugated verb.

Hence

> On est==>On a (avoir conjugated) été (participe passé of the verb
>   être)
>
> On est ==> On a été

which may interpreted according to context by various ways in English, including

> one is/people are/we are/they are ==> one has been/people have been/we have/they have been or one was/people were/we were/they were

See [here for the personal subject pronoun on](https://www.frenchtoday.com/blog/french-grammar/understanding-french-on-subject-pronoun) or even better [here](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/on) (not for beginners).

There are three major groups of verbs in French; the first two regular. The third one contains the so-called irregular verbs. Nevertheless, one can split this group into sub-groups to facilitate learning. One of the major tasks of a beginner is to learn how to conjugate the verbs of the third group and how to learn the past participle of them. The first two are not hard at all.
[See here for more](https://www.frenchtoday.com/blog/french-verb-conjugation/secret-to-master-french-verb-conjugation).

As in many other languages (English, German, Romanian) the verb être (to be) is highly irregular in terms of conjugation and constructing the past participle (été).

Last but not least French language is full of **homographes** (and homonymes more general). You have just encounter one homographe (été = summer but été = been).
[See here for more about this subject](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homographe).

I suggest also you use an online dictionary. For instance

https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/%C3%A9t%C3%A9/31337/homonyme

Comment: Great! If you could just remove the ***we are*** from *On est=one is*. As it is not correct to understand *on* as *nous*.

Comment: @aCOSwt Thanks. But we don't use (at least in everyday language) on in place of nous?

Comment: *On* can refer at group of people, but can also represent a group where the number of people can be ... undetermined; for example, we can say *On a gagné !* (refered to football) can represent all a country, but *Nous avons gagné* didn't, must be use for a group of few people

Comment: @damadam Ok. C'est noté. I made the change. Thanks!

Comment: @damadam *Nous* can be used for a group of whatever size. Dimitris' original translation was actually better than "one has been" which is a corner case.

Comment: @jlliagre can you add an example for this case? I don't see how I can use *Nous* instead of *On* for a group of ... all around 5000 or more people

Comment: I insist : Just **do not** translate *on* undefined singular by "we" defined plural. (And don't use *on* instead of *nous*). Not to say that a group often governs plural : *the police are... the team are...*

Comment: @aCOSwt I am puzzled:-)! According to https://www.frenchtoday.com/blog/french-grammar/understanding-french-on-subject-pronoun we may interpret on by one/we/I/he depending on the context. In any case the interpretation with one is rather literary if not archaic. I doubt English people use one in everyday speaking.

Comment: @dimitris : If you don't like *one* then just say *people*

Comment: @aCOSwt Ok. I will edit my answer. Thanks again:-)!

Comment: @aCOSwt There is zero context in the OP question. We do not know if it is spoken or formal written French. Telling a French learner not to use *on* to translate "we" while 99% of native French speakers do it everyday is questionable.

Comment: @damadam [nous sommes sept milliards d'habitants](http://www.lepoint.fr/monde/nous-sommes-sept-milliards-d-habitants-30-10-2011-1390774_24.php)

Comment: @jlliagre ahem ... **Wasted** :(